# Connect Calendar to CalDAV server

Tags: release-loki, calendar

I'm trying to connect Calendar to caldav.one.com. I've setup everything up as per the instructions from one.com. Still when I enter my Username and Password and click OK I get back to the same window asking for my Username and Password. I'm using caldav.one.com on my phone and it works just fine. Any ideas what is going wrong in Calendar?